# Index of components in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am trying to make a JFrame has 16 JButton by 4x4.

If I use JPanel with GridLayout(4,4),
the index of order is like below.

```
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

However, I want to make a panel with order like below.

```
(0)(1)(2)(3)
 0  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  1 
 2  2  2  2 
 3  3  3  3
```

To setup my panel like above,
what layout should I use, 
and which method should I use to get components in each column?

Comment: That makes no sense.  The components are maintained in a `List` (or for argument sake an array), each index maintains a reference to a unique component, two components can't share the same index.  Of course, I could be misunderstanding the question

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to add 4 JButtons 16 (Or 20?) times, right?

Then why create 16 JButtons? I see two posible solutions:

1. You can create 4, and add each JButton to the JPanel 4 (or 5?) times.
2. You can create 4, and create 3 (Or 4?) copies of each of the 4 initial      JButtons, then add all of them to the JPanel.

(I´m not sure what the (0)(1)(2)(3) is, that´s why I write (Or X?) all the time)